# Logging a variable to the console

Tags: javascript

How do I log the variable totalCost to the console? I am getting an error when trying to run this code

Tried using `console.log(totalCost);`

```
function monitorCount(rows, columns) {
  return rows * columns;
}

function costOfMonitors(rows, columns){
  return monitorCount(rows, columns) * 200;

  const totalCost = costOfMonitors(5, 4);

}

console.log(totalCost);
```

Comment: Are you ever calling the function? And you need to return from the function. Also, always post the error you're getting.

Comment: Why is the `const totalCost` **inside** the `costOfMonitors` function?

Comment: You return from your `costOfMonitors` function before you set `totalCost`

Comment: @Carcigenicate - despite that, `totalCost` is scoped, so the OP is going to get an `totalCost is not defined error anyway`

Comment: What does the error tell you?  What do you expect to be logged to the console from exactly this code and why?  (Honestly, there is a *variety* of problems in this code...)

Answer (score 3):

The `return` keyword ends a function after the code in its line has been executed.

Also, `totalCost` is in the scope of your `countOfMonitors` function, so you can't access it from somewhere else.

To add to that, even if you swapped your `return` statement and your declaration, you would create an infinite loop with recursion, as you're calling a the same function inside a function.

This should get it working:

```js
function monitorCount(rows, columns) {
  return rows * columns;
}

function costOfMonitors(rows, columns){
  return monitorCount(rows, columns) * 200;
}
const totalCost = costOfMonitors(5, 4);
console.log(totalCost);
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that! worked a treat!!!! new to this Java Script!!!!! ahhhhhh!!